# How do you overload dependent on what an object is an instance of?

Tags: java, operator-overloading, instanceof

I've been instructed to create two methods that overload eachother. One should store an object in one array, and the other should store an object in the other array. The assignment reads:

*Redo your Zoo so that it has the ability to storing wild animals and domestic animals separately.
Your Zoo class will therefore **probably/presumably** have two different add()  methods.
One that receives an Animal-object that implements the interface for wildlife and an add() method that receives Animal objects that implement the interface for domestic animals.*

How do I do this?

```
Class Zoo {
...
void add(Animal foobar instanceof Wild){
[...]
}
[...]
```

will not compile. Nor does

```
Class Zoo {
...
void add(Animal foobar implements Wild){
[...]
}
[...]
```

One could, in reality, use instanceof to do an if statement in add(), but he is specifically asking for two add() methods that overload eachother. How do I do this? Or, is this impossible, and my teach is trying to mess with me by saying probably/presumably?

Comment: ``void add(Animal animal)`` and ``void add(Wild animal)``. Find good java tutorial and read about methods.

Comment: @user996142 - That's not quite correct. The question stated that the `Animal` objects can implement two different interface types.

Comment: @DavidRTribble yes, it should be ``void add(Wild animal) and void add(Domestic animal)`` then, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is to provide two `add()` methods, one that takes one type of parameter (a *wildlife* animal type) and another one that takes the other type of parameter (a *domestic* animal type).

You should have enough information to code this now.

**Addendum** *(March 2016)*

For example, this is the kind of code you could use:

```
class Animal { ... }

interface Wildlife { ... }
interface Domestic { ... }

class WildAnimal
    extends Animal
    implements Wildlife
{ ... }

class DomesticAnimal
    extends Animal
    implements Domestic
{ ... }

class Zoo
{
    void add(WildAnimal beast) { ... }
    void add(DomesticAnimal beast) { ... }
}
```

Both `Zoo.add()` methods accept an argument of type `Animal`. But one accepts an `Animal` object that implements the `Wildlife` interface, and the other accepts
an `Animal` object that implements the `Domestic` interface.

Comment: True, strangely though, we did not to my knowledge explore that an interface can be used as a datatype. That is what we are doing here, yes?

Comment: Yep. Sometimes interface types are used as [*marker types*](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=marker+interface), which do not actually provide any extra methods but provide a way of "marking" different types.

Comment: So the correct term is that we're using the interface Wild as a marker type, not data type, yes?

Comment: @SvenGren - Depends on whether the `Wild` type adds other methods or behaves differently than the base `Animal` type. If it does not add any different functionality or attributes, then yes, it's being used as just a marker type.